# How to make ball bounce

Tags: c#, windows, unity-game-engine, 2d, c#-2.0

I have a game where u bounce a ball with platform and u have to destroy all boxes but my code for bounceing ball its not working like I want.

It works like a real ball bounce but I want the ball to bounce like a ball in pong where ball don't fall down until it touches wall or platfotm but my ball goes in real life curve.

What I thing with curve is like when u kick a ball in the air and goes in curve but I want it to go unlimitly in flat line to the wall andbounce in a random direction.

Someone have any code ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a physics material like the one below and place it on any surface that bounces. It is enough for your ball to have a `Rigidbody` with drag 0.

[image]

---

Also uncheck gravity to get the following result:

[image]

[image]

---

### Basic Force Script:

After adding Rigidbody to the ball, you can use the following script for the initial force. Obviously you need more advanced algorithms for further development.

```cs
public Vector3 force = new Vector3(80, 40);
void Start() => GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(force);
```

Comment: How do i go on this bounce option and where do i uncheck the gravity

Comment: For physics material : Right click on asset folder > Create > Physics Material, Click sphere > Component > Physics > Rigidbody > (inspector) uncheck  `Use Gravity`

Comment: Oh i see but i see that in my question tags is 3d unity I tried to edit it but it doesnt let my so what do I do for 2d bouncing

Comment: @HIpex You need to do the same process for 2d. Not so different.

Comment: But on rigit body 2d isn't gravity option.

Comment: @HIpex you can set the gravity scale to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Pong/breakout style physics is simpler than you might think.
The balls have no gravity applied to them, so all you need to do is apply a constant velocity to the ball.
When it collides with an object, you would flip the velocity on the axis it collided.

For example:
ball is travelling up at 60px/sec, and horizontally at 120px/sec, at 60fps.
You add (60/60)=1 pixels vertically every frame, and (120/60)=2 horizontally.
It hits a wall, so you flip the horizontal velocity to -120px/sec.
Now it's still going up, but in the opposite direction horizontally.
If it hits a ceiling, same thing but flip the vertical velocity component.

If you'd rather it go in a random direction:

- calculate the magnitude of the ball's velocity `sqrt(vx^2+vy^2)`
- find the angle the wall is facing
- pick a random angle within 180 degrees of that angle
- use trigonometry to get the x/y components of that angle, and multiply by the magnitude.

Don't subtract/add a constant value to the velocity every frame, because then you'd be applying gravity, which isn't what you're looking for.

Comment: And how do I do this in code?