# Looking for a way to make a cube in which game objects bounce around

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My question is quite simple. How do I make a cube which has other game objects inside of it, and can detect when those objects collide with sides of the cube. I can just use a collider for each of the sides but I want to be able to shrink and grow the cube while the program is running. If I used a collider for each of the sides I would have to move each of them individually. Is there a way to use just one collider on the cube?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make ball bounce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72328120/how-to-make-ball-bounce)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place six flat cubes around with a thin collier box and then make parent them to an `empty game object`.